# change font of gwtbootstrap3 app

Tags: gwt, fonts, gwtbootstrap3

I'm using gwtbootstrap3 for my app and I want to change font of all my app, I want to do something like this:

```
body{
   font-family:tahoma;
}
```

I tried to customise widget, but I have to do this fo all my widgets and I don't think it's very optimal.
So how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be one of those infrequent cases where you want to use `!important`, i.e.:

```
body{
   font-family:tahoma !important;
}
```

Before you do, however, read [When Using !important is the Right Choice](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/).